# What makes flannel so popular?

Tags: clothing

The [flannel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flannel) shirt is extremely popular when it comes to outdoor activities since ever.

[image: Flannel shirt]

> Flannel is a soft woven fabric, of various fineness. Flannel was
> originally made from carded wool or worsted yarn, but is now often
> made from either wool, cotton, or synthetic fiber.

Which characteristics made (and make) flannel such an excellent choice for outdoor activities?

---

Edit:

This question is clearly not opinion-based. One shouldn't answer with things like "Because it looks cool" or something but with rational facts.

Comment: Have you ever *worn* a flannel?

Comment: Does mouching around my teenage bedroom around 1993 listening to smashing pumpkins count as an outdoors activity? If it does I can verify it's effectiveness. :)

Comment: @Liam Did you have a roof back then? ;P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Besides being the manliest thing you could ever wear outdoors:

## Durability

Have you ever had a flannel shirt, or pair of pants? If you have, then odds are you *still* have them. They are extremely abrasion resistant, and won't melt or burst into flames if a hot coal from the fire lands on them. There's a reason why lumberjacks favoured flannel shirts, and it's because they could hack away at trees all day, carry logs around, get covered in dirt, bark, and wood chips, then at the end of the day just brush it off and go woo the ladies in the tavern.

## Warmth

Flannel is traditionally made out of wool, which is extremely warm and has a lot of merits when it comes to moisture control. You can sweat in a flannel shirt out in the cold without the shirt losing much of its insulating properties.

Comment: +1: In my part of the world, "flannel" is widely accepted as being cotton based and frowned on because its a wet and cool climate, To avoid the ambiguity, we tend to use "bush shirt" and "wool" for wool based flannel.

Comment: Lumberjacks and flannel in the same answer. Now I can't stop humming Monty Python's "I'm a lumberjack".....

Comment: Manliest than [the skin of a lion that you killed with your bare hands?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemean_lion#The_First_Labour_of_Hercules)

Answer (score 1):

Man, that's easy. It's soft, warm and durable.