# Advantages of a (hunting) hat in the woods?

Tags: gear, hunting, forests, hunting-gear

I feel like hats are quite popular among hunters and other outdoor-people which are mainly active in the woods. Also, a lot of outdoor brands have hats in [their range](http://www.fjallraven.de/sormland-felt-hat).

Which *rational* characteristics makes it preferable over "bare-headed" for some?

[image: Traveler hat]

---

Side-note:

*One shouldn't answer with things like "Because it looks cool" or something but with rational facts. 
Just like [this](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/10280/what-makes-flannel-so-popular) question.*

Comment: They reflect sound coming upward back to you ears - foots steps are amplified as is the sound of rain drops in heavy rain- this can be enough to drown out other sounds. This is the reason I stopped wear such a hat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the woods, there are many small items that can fall from above that are more or less awkward to have on your head. This goes from leaves and needles on the "not very harmful" side over water droplets (during or after the rain) to ugly things like bird poop.

One characteristic that makes a hat as depicted in your question preferable over other headdresses like a bandana is its brim. It does not only prevent things from falling directly onto your head but also that it falls onto your face – people who have to wear glasses know the awkward moment when a water droplet falls between their forehead and glasses, wetting the glass from the inside and splashing into your eyes – or into the collar of your jacket. Additional pro's are sun protection and shading of the eyes against low sun and in some communities they are just part to the style one wears when going into the woods...

Answer (score 8):

Hats are great for many reasons. They keep sun off your head, they retain heat when it's cold. They help keep small stuff from hitting your head and sometimes your face. A branch may knock your hat askance rather than scratch your face up or even poke you in the eye. It can keep that same branch from getting tangled in your hair.

A hat is just another layer of protection from the elements on a spot that is often left unprotected except by your hair if you are lucky enough have your hair.

Comment: True but a bandana looks much more manly with a shaved head and a polearm. :)

Answer (score 1):

I wear hats and try to cover most of my body when going through thicker brush.  I personally don't like when burrs, pricker bushes, or any of the other a-hole plants out there lash out on my head.  Hats allow me to charge head first into some of those in order to help shield my face from them as well.

Plus, depending on the climate, hats are good for both keeping me warm and keeping sweat out of my eyes.  I also prefer brimmed hats for sun protection since I don't often wear sunglasses while trekking through the woods.

Then, there are a select group of people who always wear hats.  As in, they never go anywhere without one on.  Whether they just like the feeling or they're trying to cover up some balding, they're a group of people manufacturers aren't likely to forget about.

Comment: More of an account of my personal experiences, which do overlap a little bit of others.  Often times with a forum like this, you're going to find answers that share bits of information with each other.  As this is primarily an opinionated question, there is no definitive "right" answer.  Providing personal viewpoints allows others to gain a more crowd-sourced answer instead of blindly agreeing with the "accepted" answer.

Comment: And in the same spirit, an answer can be removed, too.  So instead of your one man vendetta, why not flag my answer instead of playing SE cowboy?

Comment: I am new to TGO, but I am an active member on other SE sites.  I know how the process works.  As I know typically with broad open-ended questions, there are multitudes of different answers with some sharing similar qualities of one another.

Comment: Simmer down now you two... :)

Comment: Gotta entertain myself at work...